# App Service Editor 404 & host "functionTimeout"

Tags: azure-functions

I have a timer function that will timeout at 30 seconds. I did some searching and found out that I can add "functionTimeout" to the hosts file of the function app. Prior to updatinghte host file, I was able to use "App Service Editor (preview)" within Azure Portal to view the host file.

I updated the host file to look like this:

here is what my host file looks like now:

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"isEnabled": true,
"excludedTypes": "Request"
}
}
}
}
```

After updating, whenever I try to use "App Service Editor (preview)" within Azure Portal, I now receive a 404 page.

Also, my function is still timing out at 30 seconds. I am not sure how I can confirm the change to to the host file. Any advice or thoughts?

Thanks,
Dan Hickman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the workaround I did to make changes successfully in the `Host.json` file using App Service Editor from the Azure Portal.**

Note: I believe the error code came when making changes in App Service Editor (Preview) for the Azure Function App is 409 which is:

```
Failed to save `host.json`: Unable to save "/host.json" Please try again later. Error Code: 409
```

**Workaround Steps:**

***- Created the Azure Function App (.NET 6 - Timer Trigger) in Visual Studio and deployed to Azure.***

[image]

***- When editing the Function App `Function.json` and `host.json` files using App Service Editor (Preview), I got the same issue as you can see below:***

[image]
[image]

***The fix I did to make the changes in the `function.json` or `host.json` or in both files is publishing the project from Visual Studio with unchecking the Run from Package file checkbox.***

[image]

> I am not sure how I can confirm the change to to the host file.

***After that in App Service Editor (Preview), you can confirm the changes made are saved successfully as shown in right top corner of the App service editor:***

**host.json**

[image]

**function.json**

[image]